# Unable to create list form(newform,editform or displayform) in SharePoint 2010

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer, list-form

Using SharePoint Designer, I am trying to create some dummy listforms (newform1,editform1 or displayform1) but when I create one it pops up the following error.

> "could not save the list changes to the server"

and even when I try to edit the existing list form lets say the newform.aspx and try to insert the SharePoint control "custom list form" it does not get drop in the form.

Comment: Hi! How about logs? Where are may be some meaningful rows. In additional, it may be permissions problem.

Comment: Have you considered customizing with InfoPath?

Comment: I have to say I had this problem and confirm that PirateErics Solution solved my problem. Great Job. Thanks. Was initially very worried I have to say as list was huge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I came across a solution which suggested to check for broken lookup columns in the list and went ahead and **deleted the broken lookup columns** (which were looking up data which was not there) and then it let me to add the forms.

Comment: do not forget to refresh Sharepoint designer for getting new Metadata after removing invalid columns

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found that issue started to appear when i tried to add field or new edit/display form to existing one, if there ware some documents in the library that were checked out or reserved by other people.
When i deleted all the items (documents) or undone their reservation i was able to add edit/display forms again.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Sharepoint 2013... For me, I also had this problem...

[Connect Problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c51ba710-f314-40ad-8387-3cb8a302677d/content-query-webpart-does-not-work-on-the-sharepoint-2013-developer-site-template?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

To see if you also have the same problem as me run the following powershell..

```
(Get-SpWeb https://url).ListTemplates | ? {$_.Name -eq $null }
```

Then if you get something with the guid "e374875e-06b6-11e0-b0fa-57f5dfd72085"

```
Disable-SPFeature -Identity "e374875e-06b6-11e0-b0fa-57f5dfd72085" -Url http://sitecollectionurl
```

will fix it. I had to delete my webcache in C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache and reopen Sharepoint designer before designer would let me create the form though.

Comment: For the hack provided by user2855480: + 100 internet points. You sir are a scholar and a saint. Why microsoft allowed something like this to break key functionality in one of their most popular products.... we will never know. But I can confirm this work around resolved one of the issues I was having.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your list has broken lookup columns.

1. If found, delete broken lookup column.
2. Close & Restart SharePoint Designer.
3. Refresh List & Libraries in Designer (This will remove corrupted lookup column from schema & will update schema).
4. Finally try to create new list form, you will be able to create list forms.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me :

delete my webcache in `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache` and reopen SharePoint designer before designer would let me create the form though. " Thanks