# Create New Form Issue

Tags: 2013, custom-list, display-form, newform

I created new custom list. I want to add a new form to the list. I'm clicking new, and I'm selecting properties then OK. But I'm getting the follow error. Why get I this error?

I tried to create new form for custom list, another site on the another server and I can do this.Do I need to make adjustments to create a form on a new site on the new server? Is there any settings? I don't find any solve :(

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check if any file with name "haber" exists or not.

Comment: Have you checked ULS?

Comment: @AmalHashim I'm sure, there isn't any file with name "haber".

Comment: Maybe run SharePoint Designer as administrator ?

Comment: Does your list has duplicate columns names?

Comment: @SlavenSemper I checked ULS logs. I found this, about list. 
"[Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 11/04/2014 15:18:05.01, Original Level: Verbose] GetUriScheme(/Lists/Duyuru)"
"The ListFormBody attribute in the forms schema was found but no child elements exist."

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri I'm running Sharepoint Designer as administrator.

Comment: @AmalHashim No, list hasn't duplicate columns names. But I deleted a columns. Does this make any problem?

Comment: @Zengel is out of the box list view working? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/98a582da-e9e7-4753-b2db-637ceb8ce3f6/sharepoint-could-not-save-the-list-changes-to-the-server

Comment: @zengel check this out http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26262/unable-to-create-list-formnewform-editform-or-displayform-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: @AmalHashim what is the broken link. How can I find this link? Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri what is the broken link. How can I find this link? Sorry, I don't know

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment you have deleted a column.

Try to close the designer and open it again so it will refresh the new column layouts.

Comment: I tried this already. I closed the designer and opened it again. But it doesn't solve.

Comment: Do you have any lookup columns in list?

Comment: No I didn't add lookup columns. @ArsalanAdamKhatri

Comment: I created a new custom list. It has title columns only. Then I tried to create new form. But I got same error again. @ArsalanAdamKhatri

Comment: It seems your Item content type is corrupted. Have you modified the Item content type by any chance? Can you clear the site recycle bin and reload SPD?

Comment: Should I clear the site? But is it dangerous? @AmalHashim

Comment: Its only the recycle bin which contains delete items.

Comment: This isn't solve. Should I any settings for add new form, in Central Adminstrator? @AmalHashim