# SharePoint 2016 On Premise NewForm Error with Designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, dashboard-designer-2013

I am using SharePoint 2016 On Premises. I am currently unable to use SharePoint Designer to create any custom form (NewForm, EditForm, DispForm). If I try I get the following error (Could not Save the list changes to the server). That is the only error I get, nothing in the SharePoint logs. I have read that this has been removed from SharePoint Online but I am using SharePoint On Premises. Is it possible that this removal has affected my on premise setup? If so how do I get it back? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using modern or classic SharePoint?

Comment: I'm using On Premise SharePoint 2016, classic. Also it's affecting every list, I cannot create a new form (edit, display) on any list. This also affects our Development and production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Are there lookup columns in the list? Have you made any changes to the SharePoint server recently(upgrade/update)?

1.Try to install SharePoint Designer Service Pack 1.

Download 32-bit Edition: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42015

Download 64-bit Edition: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42009

2.Try to install SharePoint Designer 2013 on another client machine and test on it.

3.Please refer to following article to clear SharePoint Designer 2013 cache:

[How to Clear Your SharePoint Designer 2010/2013 Cache](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33469.how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache.aspx)

4.Restart the server.

Another similar question:

[“could not save the list changes to the server” in designer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/205243/could-not-save-the-list-changes-to-the-server-in-designer/281121)

Comment: Hi Emily, this got it working on most lists though I am still having the same issue with one list that does have lookups. I read elsewhere this problem could happen if lookups are looking to a another location that doesn't exist but that's not the problem. All the lookups are pointing to the correct locations and all lookups work.